# How to query parse for a specific item and prevent duplicates from being saved

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to prevent duplicated items from being duplicated by querying for two objects a user and an item. If they exist then do not duplicate but if it doesn't exist then make an instance of it. I know that it keeps running and makes several duplicates depending on number of items present in parse. Does anyone know how to prevent it from duplicating those values?

```
func addUserToItem(userID:String,myItemID:String,currCommit:Float) {    
    let query = PFQuery(className: "UserToItem")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Got an error here")
        } else {                    
            print(objects)

            for object in objects! {
                print("ok")
                guard let userInformation = object.objectForKey("username") as? String else {
                    print("didnt work")
                    return
                }

                guard let itemInformation = object.objectForKey("currentItem") as? String else {
                    print("didnt work2")
                    return
                }
                var isThere = false

                if (userInformation == userID) && (itemInformation == myItemID) {                    
                    print("It exists")
                    isThere = true                                       
                }

                if !isThere {
                    print("it worked")

                    let myProduct = PFObject(className: "UserToItem")
                    myProduct.setObject(userID, forKey: "username")
                    myProduct.setObject(myItemID, forKey: "currentItem")
                    myProduct.setObject(currCommit, forKey: "UserCommit")
                    myProduct.setObject(true, forKey: "Viewed")                
                    myProduct.saveInBackground()
                    isThere = true
               }                      
           }         
       }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mean to be answering my own question, but I figured it out. It is working right now as planned. Here is my code. It works right now, but then again I though my earlier solutions worked too except they didn't afterwards. Does this look good to everyone? Would this give me a headache later on?

```
 func addUserToItem(userID:String,myItemID:String,currCommit:Float) {



    let query = PFQuery(className: "UserToItem")


    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: userID)
    query.whereKey("currentItem", equalTo: myItemID)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in



        if error != nil {
            let myProduct = PFObject(className: "UserToItem")

            myProduct.setObject(userID, forKey: "username")
            myProduct.setObject(myItemID, forKey: "currentItem")
            myProduct.setObject(currCommit, forKey: "UserCommit")
            myProduct.setObject(true, forKey: "Viewed")

            myProduct.saveInBackground()
        } else {
            print("it exists")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used NSSet for store unique objects.

Comment: I tried doing an NSSet but it still makes a duplicate of that item on parse.